# Increase image quality using Html2Canvas

Tags: javascript, jspdf, html2canvas

I'm using Html2Canvas + JsPDF to export div as pdf file. But It lost quality of text. I'm using this code for it. where is problem?
.

```
        html2canvas($(element)[0],{
            allowTaint: true, 
            scale: 2,
            width: $('.report-content').css('width').split('px')[0],
            height: $('.report-content').css('height').split('px')[0]
        }).then(function(canvas) {
            pdfsave(canvas, format, PDF_Width, PDF_Height);
        });
```

Comment: I tried around with this two frameworks some month ago for many days and after that I give it up. For me there was no solution to get a high quality pdf with images and text combined. But hopefully you will find a solution

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff but what you use istead of it?

Comment: I moved to create the pdf in the backend with PHP.